# gulp not working correctly

Tags: sass, gulp

I have a few questions regarding my gulpfile.js setup.

Here is my gulp file setup:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var preserveFirstComment = function() {
    var set = false;

    return function() {
        if (set) return false;
            set = true;
            return true;
    };
};

    gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

    gulp.task('styles:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss',['styles']);
});

    gulp.task('uglify', function() {
        gulp.src('lib/marked.js')
            .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: preserveFirstComment()}))
            .pipe(concat('marked.min.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
    });

gulp.task('default', ['uglify']);
```

Once I try to run the my project with gulp all it does is run these 5 lines below and then stops and goes back to the command line prompt. I don't understand why this is happening. I am a beginner in using gulp as this is just a basic setup from a tutorial I used to setup my project.

```
C:\Users\Gemini\Documents\workspace\ca_>gulp
[20:28:16] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\workspace\ca_\Gulpfile.js
[20:28:16] Starting 'uglify'...
[20:28:16] Finished 'uglify' after 21 ms
[20:28:16] Starting 'default'...
[20:28:16] Finished 'default' after 13 μs

C:\Users\Gemini\Documents\workspace\ca_>
```

Link: [Getting Started with Gulp](http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-gulp-and-sass/)

Comment: Do **not** post your code as a screenshot. Copy&paste the code into your question and [use the appropriate formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Can you please post the output to the command line and not as an image

Comment: I've updated my post...Please see the output and the code in my gulpfile.js

Comment: I don't get it. Gulp did exactly what you told it to do. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: To watch for changes in stylesheet and compile sass to css file but it just doesn't do that. I am not sure why

Comment: It seems to be working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you only enter `gulp` on the command line Gulp executes the `default` task which in your case depends on the `uglify` task and not on `styles:watch`. That's why you only see `uglify` and `default` in Gulp's output.

If you want to execute the `styles:watch` task you have to tell Gulp explicitly so:

```
C:\Users\Gemini\Documents\workspace\ca_> gulp styles:watch
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Sven's answer above, you can add many Gulp tasks to start watching on a `gulp watch` command.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('./css/', ['styles']);
   gulp.watch('.', ['uglify']);
   // more watch things here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a gulp task, the command used is `gulp <TASK NAME>` and when we run just`gulp`, the default task is run. If, in case a default task is not defined, an error is shown mentioning `Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile`.

In this case, gulp runs the default task which is 'uglify' and that is the reason why you are not able to watch the changes in the SASS. For watching the changes in the SASS, you could modify the default task to:

```
gulp.task('default', ['uglify', 'styles:watch']);
```

This would help you out.